# How to find value within a range - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two columns in a table like below

```
  id  start end  point
  1    50    70    5
  2    80    100   7
```

How can find the value's range in my code below.. Now when i submit the mark (70), i want to find the range it belongs to so i can get the respective points.

```
   lets say $marks = 70
   public function getGrade($marks)
          {
            $grade_point = Grade::where(function ($query) use ($marks) {
              $query->where('from', '<=', $marks);
              $query->where('to', '>=', $marks);
           return $grade_point->point;
 }
```

With the code above i get the error

> > Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the query with a method like `get()`, `first()`, `pluck('column')`, `value('column')`....

```php
lets say $marks = 70
public function getGrade($marks)
{
    $grade_point = Grade::where('from', '<=', $marks)->where('to', '>=', $marks);
    return (int)$grade_point->value('point');
}
```

the method `value('column')` returns the column's value of the firsts result or null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `->first()`, `->get()` or `->all()` to execute to the query:

```
//  lets say $marks = 70
public function getGrade($marks)
{
    $grade_point = Grade::where(function ($query) use ($marks) {
        $query->where('from', '<=', $marks);
        $query->where('to', '>=', $marks);
    })->first();

    return $grade_point->point;
}
```

Checkout the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results